# In SystemVerilog, is there a way to use assertions in constant functions?

Tags: system-verilog

I have a function akin to this

```
function automatic int divide(int a,  int b);
        check_divides: assert(a % b == 0);

        return a / b;
endfunction
```

My simulator refuses to compile this and says this is no longer a constant function.

Does anyone know if this should be allowed or if there is a way to perform assertions like this in constant functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in Questa. Although there is nothing in the LRM section *13.4.3 Constant functions* to suggest that this is illegal, there is also nothing that defines the behavior the action block of the assertion and its effect on compilation.

Comment: Had a look through that section. Granted a constant function should of course only be able to use other constant functions and constant system functions. But as far as I can tell the standard is vague about what system functions are constant system functions.

Comment: I was also surprised to find this: "Constant functions shall not themselves use constant functions in any context requiring a constant
expression." Why should it not be possible to call another constant function from within a constant function?

Comment: General nesting of function calls is not the restriction. It's when you call a constant function, but before you can execute that function, it has to call another constant function that defines a parameter or range to finish the declaration of first function. It's not impossible, but very difficult to implement.